# Why Ruby convention is not followed for Array#keep_if?

Tags: ruby

There is a Ruby convention for method naming using bang(`!`). The convention is if the method changes `self`, we use bang to let know others about the self modifying bahaviour.

For example `Array#select` doesn't change `self`, but `Array#select!` does. But `Array#keep_if` does change self. There is nothing called `Array#keep_if!`.

What might be the reason for not following the convention?

Comment: There are several methods that change `self` whose names do not end with an exclamation point, such as the `Array` methods `delete`, `delete_at` and `delete_if`. I assume these are not banged because it's obvious from the name that they change `self` (though `String#delete` does not!). By extension, since `keep_if` is the opposite of `delete_if` the former is not banged either. `Array#concat` is an example of another method that is not banged because it's obvious that it changes `self`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matz, the creator of Ruby, wrote:

> The bang (!) does not mean "destructive" nor lack of it mean non
>   destructive either.  The bang sign means "the bang version is more
>   dangerous than its non bang counterpart; handle with care".  Since
>   Ruby has a lot of "destructive" methods, if bang signs follow your
>   opinion, every Ruby program would be full of bangs, thus ugly.

Source: [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/176830#773946)

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception. The bang method is used to distinguish between a dangerous and a safe version of the same method. It does not mean that it will necessarily change its receiver.

Comment: Actually, it's really about "more suprising" and "less surprising". There's nothing inherently dangerous about `Process::exit!`, for example.